# How to edit strings in a list

Tags: python-3.x

What I want is this - I have a list of names created from user input. now i have to come up with a way for the user to edit a name by entering the name that they what to edit and then obviously edit it into what they want and store it in the list.

if it helps heres everything I have so far. def edit() is where im struggling.

```
def mainMenu():
    print("\nMAIN MENU")
    print("1. Display Members:")
    print("2. Add A Member(s):")
    print("3. Remove A Member:")
    print("4. Edit Member:")
    print("5. Exit:")
    selection = int(input("\nEnter Choice: "))
    if selection == 1:
        display()
    elif selection == 2:
        add()
    elif selection == 3:
        remove()
    elif selection == 4:
        edit()
    elif selection == 5:
        exit()
    else:
        print("Invalid choice, enter 1-5.")
        mainMenu()

def display():
    #displaying roster...
    print(roster)
    mainMenu()

def add():
    #adding team members...
    size = int(input("How many players are you adding?"))
    global roster
    roster = [0] * size
    for i in range(size):
        roster[i] = input("Enter members name: ")
    roster.append(roster)
    mainMenu()

def remove():
    #removing a team member...
    roster.remove(input("Enter member to be removed: "))
    mainMenu()

def edit():
    #edit a team member...
    roster.insert(input("Enter Name to be edited: "))
    mainMenu()

mainMenu()
```

Comment: Indent your code properly please. There is a toolbar button that will indent blocks of code for you.

Comment: What does "struggling" mean? Are you getting an error? An unexpected result? Please elaborate.

Comment: Well I simply just dont know what to put there..

Comment: I want the user to edit the list. I dont want to edit it in the code. Does that make sense?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Removing and adding elements are pretty easy in python because they are directly supported by the language. Each of them can be translated into only one instruction.

When something doesn't seem very obvious, such as the editing functionality you are trying to implement, try breaking it down to things that can be expressed as a simple operation that holds one one line (even if not in order).

To find the answer I thought this: *somewhere in my code, I want to type* `roster[ind_name_to_edit] = new_name`.

I knew then that before typing this, I would want to find the value of `ind_name_to_edit`. This can be done by `roster.index(name_to_edit)`. And you already know how to get the name to be edited and the name to edit ;)

If you're still unsure how to do what you want to do, re-read this answer and see [the documentation of the index method of list in python3](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html) and maybe some examples [here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/list_index.htm).

**N.B:** If your list is supposed to be sorted in some way, you should implement your own search algorithm instead of using index, and you should consider re-sorting the list after the edit. I know it's a long shot but just in case.

Comment: I tried roster.index(input("Name to edit: ")) = input("New Name: ") but it says cant assign to function call.

Comment: Try separating: s1=input("Name to edit: "); s2=input("New Name: "); ind=roster.index(s1); roster[ind]=s2;

Comment: awesome thank you that did the job. Dont really understand why though.

Comment: You're welcome! The problem in "roster.index(input("Name to edit: ")) = input("New Name: ")" was that the part before the = sign evaluated to an index, which is a number. You can not assign a function call, or anything in general, to a  number.

The solution I gave you in my last comment used variables to be able to separate things and see clearly which instruction returns what

Comment: @Zack You're looking for `roster[roster.index(input("Name to edit: "))] = input("New Name: ")`